# VBA insert Field, filename and path

Tags: vba, ms-word, filepath

I have my code for the footer,page number, current file name, and image of footer block, but I want to be able to insert a field to get the file name and path, and be able to update that. the problem is that it doesn't contain the path file and that its not automatic. [image: What I want to be able to do automatically] Maybe you can help...

```
'Page Number & Footer Algorithm
    With wdapp.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(1).range.Paragraphs(1)
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    '.Insert.quickparts.Field.Filename
      .range.InsertBefore Text:=Left(ActiveDocument.Name, _
  Len(ActiveDocument.name))
  .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight

    .range.InsertAfter vbCr & "Page "
    Set r = .range
    E = .range.End
    r.Start = E
    .range.Fields.Add r, wdFieldPage
    .range.InsertAfter " of "
   E = .range.End
   r.Start = E
   .range.Fields.Add r, wdFieldNumPages
    .range.InsertAfter vbCr
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .range.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("X:\EQP\Residential Maintenance Agreement\Footer Template.PNG")
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the filename with path try something like this:

```
TargetRange.Fields.Add Range:=TargetRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="FILENAME  \p ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```

In your case `TargetRange` could be something like:

```
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
```

You may need to play with `TargetRange`, including making the first and second occurrences different, to get the filename where you want it.

As for automatically updating, that looks trickier. According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/196703/how-do-i-update-all-fields-in-a-word-document), fields placed in headers or footers update when you print or print preview, otherwise you have to manually force an update. The answer links to another answer that purports to be a VBA solution to this problem.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job

```
    .range.Fields.Add range:=.range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="FILENAME  \p ", PreserveFormatting:=True
```